# ExpressJS - Call an outer function in router.get and render its data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I need to call functions in order to render mysql queries data to my views instead of having the query functions inside the `router.get`

How can I call a `function()` inside `router.get` so I can render its query output through EJS or any other templating engine?

**index.js**

```
function fdb(mypar) {
    obj = {}
    con.query(mypar, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err
        obj = rows[0]
        console.log(obj)
        //rows data fetching OK using stored procedure get_all_1 when route '/' is called
    })
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fdb('CALL get_all_1')
    console.log(obj) // {}

    to_render = { print: obj } 
    console.log(to_render) // { print: {} }

    res.render('index', to_render); 
    //it obviously cannot render anything
    //GET / 500 
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<% print.forEach(function (qdata) { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= qdata.name %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= qdata.location %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% }) %>
```

I understannd somehow that `obj` gets out of scope when I try to call it through `fdb()` function inside the `router.get` but can't figure out how to manipulate that scope.

Comment: @Cadmos Mark the answer if that solve your problem .

Comment: @Vasikos - If I thought that was an answer to the question, I would have put it in an actual answer.  The OP is using undeclared variables in server-based asynchronous code.  That's a recipe for disaster.  It's wrong code that can cause bugs and they should be declared with `var`, `let` or `const`.  I was educating them that they should fix that.  Nowhere did I say the variable declaration issue is an answer.  The link I referenced, on the other hand, does explain exactly what is wrong with `fdb()` and how to return an asynchronous result which is what they need to do.

Comment: @Vasikos - This is one thing comments are for here - to point out additional things about the code that are not being postured as solutions, but are additional things the OP should know.  And, if they continue to program that way using undeclared (implicit globals) in asynchronous code, their code will be full of bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this . You can use callback function  for this .

```
function fdb(mypar, callback) {
    con.query(mypar, (err, rows) => {  
         callback(err,rows);

    })
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    fdb('CALL get_all_1',function(err,obj){

    if (err) throw err;
    obj = rows[0]
    console.log(obj);
    to_render = { print: obj } 
    console.log(to_render) // { print: {} }
    res.render('index', to_render);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fdb(mypar) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    obj = {}
    con.query(mypar, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) throw err
      obj = rows[0]
      console.log(obj)
      resolve(obj);
    })
  });
}

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
  let obj = await fdb('CALL get_all_1')
  console.log(obj)

  to_render = { print: obj } 
  console.log(to_render)

  res.render('index', to_render); 
});
```

Comment: Also need to fix  of the undeclared variables so multiple routes don't trounce each other by sharing a global.